# QDateTime: add current year automatically

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, datetime

I need to get a `QDateTime` object from the format `"hh:mm:ss"`. where year, month and day should be taken from current date?

Would anyone suggest any cleaner solution other than prepending `yyyy-mm-dd` to the input string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the current date/time using [`QDateTime::currentDateTime()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#currentDateTime), then use [`setTime()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#setTime) to set the time you want:

```
QDateTime dateTime= QDateTime::currentDateTime();
dateTime.setTime(QTime::fromString("11:11:11", "hh:mm:ss"));
```

#### EDIT:

In order to get a `QDateTime` object when the format of the input string is `"MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`, while setting the year as the current year, I would do something like this:

```
QDateTime dateTime= QDateTime::fromString("12/17 11:11:11", "MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
//get current date
QDate currentDate= QDate::currentDate();
//get read date
QDate readDate= dateTime.date();
//assign new date by taking year from currentDate, month and days from readDate
dateTime.setDate(QDate(currentDate.year(), readDate.month(), readDate.day()));
```

Please note that when a field is not present in the input format, [`QDateTime::fromString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1) uses some default values. In this case, the year is set to 1900 until it is assigned to the current year in the last line.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for the blunder. Do you have any ideas of how would you do it if "MM" is also present in the string?

Comment: @ff2 , never mind, no problem :) Do you want to discard that input "MM"? or do you want to set it as the month for your final `QDateTime` object?

Comment: well, My application actually has the datetime of the format ``"MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`` . I want the datetime for it with the current year. Going by ur method, I will need to discard the ``"MM/dd"``. Don't know how? Presently I am appending year at the start and doing the parsing.

Comment: @ff2 , please see my edit. Personally, I would avoid prepending the current year to the input string, since it is an unnecessary string operation. But I guess, both solutions are Ok.